# Replace div background by file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I want to replace the background of my div by the uploaded file. 
Note that this div is my Upload Button, and that its background changes on :hover and :active. 
When the file should be uploaded to the background, the :hover and :active attributes should not have effect.

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input id="uploader1" type="file" accept="image/*" style="display:none;" required>
<label for="uploader1">
     <div class="square" id="myImg1"></div>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
.square{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.square:before{
    padding-top: 95%;
    display:block;
    content: "";
}
#myImg1 {
 background: url('button.jpg') no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
}
#myImg1:hover {background:url('buttonHover.jpg') no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
}
#myImg1:active {
background:url('buttonClick.jpg') no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
}
#uploader1 > input {
display:none;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/8y98uds6/)

Comment: ok, what's the question?

Comment: I want to replace the background of my div by the uploaded file.

Comment: ok, what have you tried? We are happy to help but can't really do it for you

Comment: I've tried the #uploader1 > input, which would work if there was no :hover and :active attributes above it, but since there are, it always ended up being replaced by the hover...

I've looked around everywhere, and i don't really know what to do anymore. I was thinking of also creating a toggle button, so if there was input, the toggle would be "on", and the css would change. but that's overthinking it.. Is there any way of doing this in a simpler way?

Like, it knows that there is input, and it changes the css to put the input as a background and ignore the :hover and :active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it for you.

I did this:

```
$("#uploader1").change(function(){
    $("#myImg1").css("background-image", "url("+URL.createObjectURL($(this)[0].files[0])+")");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8y98uds6/2/